# I have python error builtins.ImportError: No module named 'nltk.tokenize'

Tags: python, import, module, nltk, tokenize

I wrote the following at the start of the script:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sword_tokenize
```

However, I get the following error:

```
builtins.ImportError: No module named 'nltk.tokenize'
```

What is the solution of this problem?

Comment: did u install nltk? which python version did u install it for ? to test, run the python interpreter and type import nltk

Answer (score 0):

Install the module.
You can use pip install or easy_install.
Please checkout how to install python modules